# How to connect mongodb and Informix server

Tags: mongodb, kundera, nosql

I am exploring mongodb , I have written a code to connect mongodb and mysql using kundera
It works fine. But I am having a requirement to connect Informix database and mongodb please let me know how to do that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert in MongoDB or NoSQL. But latest Informix fixpack (12.10.xC2) supports native MongoDB connectivity and JSON/BSON.
Not all the features/commands of MongoDB are available (it's not meant to "replace" MongoDB), but it's probably the easiest way to interact with it from a "MongoDB app".
The main problem with this approach would probably be that your current Informix environment isn't running 12.10.xC2 (just released on September 13).

Please check it on the official Infocenter on IBM site. You can download the new version if you're a customer with active support. Otherwise you can get it from IBM website (either the developer edition or the free - as in beer - version called Innovator-C)

Regards

Comment: I've actually been able to use mongo (shell) to transfer data between Informix tables and MongoDB instance collections. Just a few lines.
Regards

Comment: kind to share the lines details? Thanks.